# smooth super scheme which is not smooth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, lie-superalgebras, supermanifolds, super-algebra

I am following the very nice  "[Notes on fundamental algebraic supergeometry](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.00700.pdf). Hilbert and Picard superschemes" by Bruzzo, Ruiperez and Polishchuk. I am having some problem in order to give some examples of situations that I think should be clear.

The authors characterize smooth superschemes in Proposition A.17. Since every for every superscheme its topological space (as ringed space) is given by the spectrum of the even part of a super ring (its bosonic reduction), it should be natural to have examples of smooth superschemes that their bosonic reduction are not smooth, or even non-smooth superschemes in which the bosonic reduction is smooth.

I would appreciate very much any hints on how to construct such examples, or even a reference for it.